# MediaWiki Apache2 RewriteEngine Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki

I am working from [Manual:Short URL/Apache guide](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) to set up a wiki with a shortened url on a Debian server running Apache2.

I want the directory /var/www/currienet/w/ to be accessible on currienet/wiki/ (local network address)

I have the following in httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName http://currienet
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/currienet/root/
      <Directory /var/www/currienet/root>
        Allow from all
      </Directory>


        <Directory /var/www/currienet/w/>

        </Directory>

      # Alias /wiki '/var/www/currienet/w'
      LogLevel debug

      # Enable the rewrite engine
      RewriteEngine On

      # Short url for wiki pages
      RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ /var/www/currienet/w/index.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

And the following settings in the LocalSettings.php

```
$wgScriptPath       = "/w";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

When I try and access currienet/wiki I get the main page displaying, but none of the images, stylesheets etc are loaded and I get the following in the Apache error log (ip's blocked out for security):

```
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.17 PHP/5.4.4-2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/currienet/root/w, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 283 to 216 : URL /w/load.php, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/currienet/root/w, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 283 to 216 : URL /w/load.php, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/currienet/root/w, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 283 to 216 : URL /w/load.php, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/currienet/root/w, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 324 to 248 : URL /w/skins/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /wiki/images/swan.png, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
[Tue Oct ***.***.***.*** 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ***.***.***.***] Zlib: Compressed 11292 to 3748 : URL /wiki/Images/swan.png, referer: http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page
```

And the following in other_vhosts_access.log:

```
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 304 276 "http://currienet/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cskins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&* HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&* HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en-gb&modules=skins.vector&only=scripts&skin=vector&* HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /w/skins/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png HTTP/1.1" 404 530 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /wiki/images/swan.png HTTP/1.1" 301 539 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:***.***.***.***.96 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "GET /wiki/Images/swan.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4209 "http://currienet/wiki/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
currienet:80 ::1 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)"
currienet:80 ::1 - - [02/Oct/2***.***.***.*** +0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few things wrong with your Apache config.

```
ServerName http://currienet
```

This should be the domain name of the site without the http://

```
ServerName currienet.blah.com
```

This directory block should explicitly state its options and access.

```
<Directory /var/www/currienet/w/>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You have commented out the one line that you need:

```
# Alias /wiki '/var/www/currienet/w'
```

Also, you should have an Alias line with an ending / on the wiki.

```
Alias /wiki/ '/var/www/currienet/w/'
```

Now, rewrites.  Rewrite rules are for mapping one url to another- not mapping a url to a directory.

```
  # Short url for wiki pages
  RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ /var/www/currienet/w/index.php [L]
```

This is not going to do what you expect (it will attempt to serve the page `http://YOURSITE/var/www/currienet/w/index.php` which probably doesn't exist).  If you've put the Alias directive in place and have properly set the Directory options for that dir then you don't need any rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This cleared up a number of semantic details I wasn't grasping or I had confused. Unfortunately, I followed your instructions and am now getting the error `The requested URL /wiki/Main_Page was not found on this server.` when I try and view currienet/wiki/